# Sitemap is not valid?

Tags: sitemap, google-index

I have created a site [ozeret.biz](http://ozeret.biz).
It's a relatively new site, I have created it something like a week ago. I have created and uploaded site map to the google and to the bing. Every system tells me that the map is valid, "fetch-as-google" works well, but the site is not being indexed. Is there any possibility to solve the issue? What am I doing wrong?